# Why does JQuery UI datepicker beforeshowday do nothing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

In the code below you can see begin and end arrays which are filled with unix timestamps. 
The same indices (begin[0],end[0]) stand for one range. 
Now my question is how can I disable those dates in the datepicker. 
I tried it with the `beforeshow` method, but that only disables the very last range. 
The else-block enables the dates before, but when I delete it, there is an exception that I have to return an array. So how can I make the datepicker do nothing for the already disabled dates?

```
<?php 

  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hmt_db");

  $hardwareId=$_POST["hardwareId"];

  $abfrage="SELECT lendFrom,lendTill FROM hardware,lending 
  WHERE hardwareId=$hardwareId 
  AND HardwareId=hardware_hardwareId";

  $from=array();
  $to=array();
  $i=0;
  $ergebnis=mysqli_query($db,$abfrage);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis)){
           $from[$i]=$row->lendFrom;
           $to[$i]=$row->lendTill;
   }

?>


var begin = <?php echo json_encode($from);?>;
var end = <?php echo json_encode($to);?>;
$(function() {

    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(),
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dateFormat: "dd. MM yy",
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            var datee = Math.floor(date.getTime()/1000);
            var array = new Array;
            for(var i = 0;i<begin.length;i++) {
                if(datee >= begin && datee <= end || $(this).attr("class")=="ui-state-disabled") {
                    return [false,""];
                } else return [true,""];
            }
        },
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
```